# Getting current day and obtaining the day before

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

I have an Android application with this snippet of code to get the current date of the system

```
public static Date getCurrentDate()
{
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();     
    c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);      
    return new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());               
}
```

Every time that a document is done I save to the database the date and the time on different fields. The problem is that sometimes the date that is saved is wrong, instead of the current day saves the day before. What is wrong with this function?

Note: On 155000 records the number of errors is 20

Comment: why are you using `Calender` while `new Date()` alone can give you current date and Time. @Plebios

Comment: I only want the date part not the time, and the question is what is wrong with the code not why I cannot use another thing

Comment: Do you really have to use the java.util Date API for this? The API is incredibly clunky and prone to errors. Joda-time (pre Java8) or the java.time API (java8) are much more readable alternatives.

Comment: If you want to zero the time part then don't forget to zero the milliseconds like this way: `c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);` This can become important in comparing the time parts.

Comment: funny error. Could you please record the time also while recording the date and check if all those error cases happen near a particular time?

Comment: Where are you storing the date values? If you are using any kind of SQL just save the time in the query, much simpler

Comment: Check joda library. https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Comment: Maybe is something related with the millisecond part. If Calendar.MILLISECOND was negative the date is the day before. I do not understand that case but it seems plausible